# access denied while renaming .exe file

Tags: .net, exe, rename

We have a application developed with VB.NET and kept in windows server 2003. Users run the apllication through network. We were using this method for updating our application

1. Create new .exe with updated code
2. Rename old .exe file while users are running the application
3. Copy new .exe in old exe path
4. Delete old .exe following day

It was working fine.But from a week it is behaving strange. Its giving error **Access denied**  while renaming sometimes. After closing application on user side it will allow to rename. And sometimes after closing application on user side .exe will be automatically deleted. What is causing this? pl help

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the application is in use somewhere..try killing the process from Task Manger and then try to rename it

Hope this helps

Comment: As i said we were renaming .exe file while users running the application in network and it was no problem earlier.And it is difficult to close all users application so we want rename while users running that application

Answer (score 0):

Just start **cmd.exe** and type rename **"\Server\share\Dir\my.exe" Old.exe.**
 You can do this over network

Comment: We did try renaming both over network and in server but not using commandline. we will try in commandline renaming. But i don't think rename "\Server\share\Dir\my.exe" Old.exe makes any difference than manually renaming